# Substitute for Chinkiang vinager

Tags: asian-cuisine

What can I sub for Chinkiang vinegar? It is for a dressing recipe I found.
Just don't want to go to the store

Answer (score 6):

In [America's Test Kitchen's recipe for Hot and Sour Soup](http://www.americastestkitchen.com/recipes/2803-hot-and-sour-soup?incode=MASAZ00L0&ref=search_results_1) (sorry, paywalled), they call for 5 tablespoons black Chinese vinegar **or** 1 tablespoon red wine vinegar plus 1 tablespoon balsamic vinegar. So a 50/50 mix of both vinegars for more than twice the amount of Chinkiang vinegar. I have made Hot and Sour Soup with Chinkiang and with the red wine and balsamic substitution. I can vouch for the substitution.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Balsamic vinegar is going to be your closest match in color and taste unless you happen to have date vinegar in your pantry. Balsamic is pretty common in every home though.

Comment: I think balsamic is often a bit sweeter and stronger? Might be worth diluting with a bit of regular rice vinegar if so.

Comment: Flavor wise I would agree but adding rice vinegar would make it much lighter in color so if presentation matters I would go without.